# Can a list's last noun help imply the common suffixial morphemes of it's sister nouns?

Tags: nuances

Sorry if the title is confusing, but the gist of it is whether the given sentence:

鶏肉とか、豚肉とか、牛肉ですよ。

May be truncated down to:

鶏とか、豚とか、牛肉ですよ。or maybe 鶏、豚、牛肉ですよ。

You know, if there're suffix morphemes that are common to all the list members, can the last element be used to imply these common morphemes in a way like those shown above. Or does Japanese not allow this like English does with multi-word noun-phrases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very interesting question.
As for the question, yes. 
The last noun of the list can help imply the common suffixial morphemes of its (not it's) sister nouns.

If the answer is yes, I know you may presume that the Japanese people are patient to the last or they are clever enough to remember how the preceding nouns become at the last. As for your presumption, I have a clear answer.

You know that the whole meaning of a Japanese sentence is decided at the last phrase like: 私は金持ちで**ある**/**ない**. The Japanese people have been trained for a long long time by this character of the Japanese language, so it's a cinch for us to wait for the last noun, whatever it becomes.

Relating to this story, I know the native speaker of English is also patient.
We say like: 豚肉と牛肉と鶏肉とを買います or 豚肉か牛肉か鶏肉かを買います while, you say like: *I'll buy pork, beef and chicken*. or *I'll buy pork, beef or chicken*.

We know at 豚肉**と**, the suffix of the first noun, the outline of what you want to say in the sentence in Japanese, but you can't know the outline of the sentence until you meet **and** at last in English.

But this is one of rare exceptions. Usually you say a key word that decides the whole meaning of what you are going to say in the early stage like: *I **know** that* / *I **don't know** that*; *There **are** A, B, C and D* / *There **is** A, B, C or D*.